# sudo grub reboot results in blackscreen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, grub-efi

I followed this guide:

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/how-to-reboot-in-windows-from-ubuntu.html

basically enabled grub reboot, updated grub, set to reboot to index 2 (3rd entry) and rebooted.

At that point I got a blackscreen and I waited for 30 seconds until I forced a manual reboot. The forced reboot showed grub having preselected (with the asterix * next to it) the 3rd entry (which is windows).

So how come I got a blackscreen after using sudo reboot? The guide is from 2010. Does win10 or uefi need different settings?

My system (dual boot) info:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64bit
- Windows 10 Edu 64bit